oracle sql query that will find records that are missing data
I am trying to set up a query that will find records that are missing data.  For example, I have a main form where users will enter biographical data, but they may be missing the birthday, the last name, and the phone number.  The idea is that this query will help us identify the records which are missing data and allow us to then go back and enter this data in when we find it.  How would I set up the query to catch the records with any missing data?
I first tried to place "Is Null" (not in quotes) in the OR section of the query, and it worked with only one field being tested, but as I added more fields it could not find a record with missing data.
As always thank you for taking the time to read this and help with this issue.  I look forward to your response.

If ypu test is null with OR operand - it has to work:
CREATE TABLE people (
    id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR2(50),
    last_name VARCHAR2(50),
    birthday DATE,
    city VARCHAR2(50)
);
/

begin

--all data
INSERT INTO people (id, first_name, last_name, birthday, city) 
VALUES (1, 'Jan', 'Kowalski', TO_DATE('1990-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'Warszawa');

-- one missing data
INSERT INTO people (id, first_name, last_name, birthday, city) 
VALUES (2, 'Anna', 'Nowak', TO_DATE('1985-05-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL);

-- 2 nulls columns
INSERT INTO people (id, first_name, last_name, birthday, city) 
VALUES (3, 'Piotr', NULL, TO_DATE('1978-03-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL);

-- 3 nulls
INSERT INTO people (id, first_name, last_name, birthday, city) 
VALUES (4, NULL, 'Wiśniewski', TO_DATE('2000-12-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL);

-- 4 nulls
INSERT INTO people (id, first_name, last_name, birthday, city) 
VALUES (5, NULL, NULL, TO_DATE('1995-07-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL);

--all nulls
INSERT INTO people (id, first_name, last_name, birthday, city) 
VALUES (6, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

end;
/

commit;


select * from people
where first_name is null or
      last_name is null or
      birthday is null or
      city is null;


If its not working probaly you have SOMETHING in this field. Check the length of the value.
INSERT INTO people (id, first_name, last_name, birthday, city) 
VALUES (7, 'Anna', 'Nowak', TO_DATE('1985-05-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), ' ');
commit;

select * from people
where first_name is null or
      last_name is null or
      birthday is null or
      city is null;
      
-- no  row id = 7


select id,  city, length(city) from people;

select * from people
where first_name is null or
      last_name is null or
      birthday is null or
      trim(city) is null;



One option is to use ANY/SOME/ALL comparison condition:
WITH      -- S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl(ID, COL1, COL2, COL3) AS
      ( Select 1, 101,  'ABC', Trunc(SYSDATE) From Dual Union All
        Select 2, Null, 'ABC', Trunc(SYSDATE) From Dual Union All
        Select 3, Null, Null, Trunc(SYSDATE) From Dual Union All
        Select 4, Null, Null, Null From Dual 
      )

... ANY (or SOME) Is Null
--    S Q L :
Select * 
From   tbl
Where  'nullValue' = ANY( Nvl(To_Char(COL1), 'nullValue'), 
                          Nvl(COL2, 'nullValue'), 
                          Nvl(To_Char(COL3), 'nullValue')
                        );

/*    R e s u l t :
        ID       COL1 COL   COL3    
---------- ---------- ----  --------
         2 null       ABC   04.07.24
         3 null       null  04.07.24
         4 null       null  null      */

... OR the opposite selection (none is null)
Select * 
From   tbl
Where  'nullValue' != ALL( Nvl(To_Char(COL1), 'nullValue'), 
                           Nvl(COL2, 'nullValue'), 
                           Nvl(To_Char(COL3), 'nullValue')
                         );

/*    R e s u l t :
        ID       COL1 COL COL3    
---------- ---------- --- --------
         1        101 ABC 04.07.24     */

NOTE:

compare same datatypes using To_Char() or Cast() if needed
you can use Coalesce() instead of Nvl()

